# S3 multiple index files

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using s3 with cloudfront.  I have an application that has two index files.

/index
/admin/index

The /index works fine the /admin/index requires me to put /admin/index.html without including index.html it throws

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>D989FEFADF688159</RequestId>
  <HostId>
    GvoytrXvDOLPu26AiYYaq6Zi4ck42xyZy3mdxlSF8q5AZc4WEphayr5o6WVDxNM7+qutIAfn53k=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

I checked the permissions on the file they are correctly set.  Additionally I can view the file when using the full url /admin/index.html.

Is this expected behavior or something wrong with my configuration of s3 / cloudfront.

Comment: Looks like you can configure CloudFront to use S3 web endpoint rather than it's REST endpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34065543/93345 . Not sure why it seems to default to the REST endpoint :p .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cloudfront is the issue.  It appears you can't have multiple index files when using cloud front. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html

I ended up adding the index.html to the route to make it work.