# Enabling SSL Certificate on Static Site

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I have the domain registered with Godaddy and using AWS `Route53` service for mapping the `S3` hosted static website to the domain name. I followed the guides & created the two buckets, primary bucket being `www.example.com` & redirecting the apex domain `example.com` to the sub-domain `www.example.com`.

Everything is fine. The website is viewable on the above two addresses.

However, I am having difficulty getting `https` SSL certificate to work.

Then I requested a certificate using the AWS `Certificate Manager` using the following settings:

```
domain name: example.com
additional name: *.example.com
```

Finally I created the `CloudFront Distribution` using the following settings

```
S3 bucket address for www.example.com bucket
alternative domain: example.com
```

& linked the custom certificate field to this newly created certificate.

Everything is enabled & I get no error, however, the address: `https://example.io` & `https://www.example.com` are still not working.

Note, It still doesn't work inspite of giving it a day to be fully operational. What am I doing wrong with setting cloudfront distribution with my s3 buckets & linking with the certificates?

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the DNS to point to CloudFront?  Or is it still pointing to S3?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that might well have been the step I was missing. I just changed the link to point to the cloudfront instead of the s3 bucket. Will update here once its up on AWS, whether its working or not. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, that didnt work, am getting a 'XML file does not appear to any style infomation associated...' error. Am going through SO questions to resolve it.

Comment: Actually, that probably did work, but you originally configured CloudFront by selecting the bucket name from the drop-down list, instead of pasting the name of the web site hosting endpoint for the bucket... see my explanation at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34065543/1695906.  The error might be `NoSuchKey` or might be `AccessDenied` but the problem is often the same. (Look for `<Code>` in the XML).

Comment: Thanks again, I have the apex domain working great, however, now the sub-domain www.example.com is giving an error: `This site can’t provide a secure connection, www.example.com uses an unsupported protocol`. Did I mess up the certificate settings & redo?