# Securing s3 Bucket while hosting Angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I know there are 2 ways of creating Cloudfront Origin:

1. paste website endpoint from s3 bucket itself;
2. select s3 from the list.

Now, when I do #1 - my site seems to really work, but I have to make bucket public. And if I'm using CF distribution for testing, I don't want everyone to have access to files in the bucket. OK, I can restrict access to CF itself with WAF/IP list. This is great.

Next I want to allow access to s3 bucket only from CF. I've found that it's achievable using #2, and I've made it, but now I have only first page of Angular app working, which is, for example, login. After login, app redirects somewhere, say /page/authenticated, and I've got an error "specified key does not exist".  I've found a beautiful [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34065543) explaining this situation.

But still, I don't uderstand, can I restrict access to s3 bucket while using s3-website endpoint? Or, if I want routing to work, I have to do s3 bucket public and no other variants?

Comment: do you look at cloudfront origin setting set the 'Origin Access Identity' to use identity? if u set it, u can make your s3 bucket as private and it only allow cloudfront to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep your bucket private and only allow access by using CloudFront.

You don't need to use the website endpoint of the bucket.

What you must do for SPA to work, including Angular, is to add custom `Error Pages`.

Go to `Error Pages` and click `Create Custom Error Response`.

Create an entry for `404` and `403`. It should look something like this

[image]

Comment: man, I love you!!1111 <3

been trying to acheve this for like half a day

Comment: ha ha, np, this is one of he biggest pains with SPA in AWS.

Comment: and, to be honest, half a day was only today. yesterday I was trying to make this thing work like full 8 hours

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late to the party, but I have recently published an article which describes in a lot of details the security best practices, which help address the following points:

- How to secure an S3 buckets, which store sensitive user data and the application code.
- How to securely configure a CloudFront distribution.
- How to protect frontend apps against common OWASP threats with CloudFront Functions.

To learn more [have a look at the article](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-you-need-to-know-to-secure-apps-with-cloudfront-functions-and-s3-d9f5c966d8a9).

Best,
Stefan