# Amazon S3 + Cloudfront React app fully working but with 404 error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a react app deployed to Amazon S3 and distributed by Cloudfront, and it is fully working as expected right now.
However, when I open the browser console, it shows a 404 error.

For example, let's say the address for my website is `https://shinhong.com`.

- Type `https://shinhong.com` in the address bar and hit Enter: **Works without errors**
- Now click some link on the website and navigate to `https://shinhong.com/path/to/something`: **Works without errors**
- Now refresh the current page (`https://shinhong.com/path/to/something`): **Works, but shows 404 error like** `GET https://shinhong.com/path/to/something 404 (Not Found)`
- Or type `https://shinhong.com/path/to/something` in the address bar and hit Enter: **Works, but shows the same error as above**

The network request with 404 error had the following response headers:

```
x-amz-cf-pop: ICN51-C1
x-amz-error-code: NoSuchKey
x-amz-error-detail-key: admin/logs
x-amz-error-message: The specified key does not exist.
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

but with response:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#2c7be5"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
...
```

which is the normal `public/index.html` file.

I have checked this link [CloudFront + S3 Website: "The specified key does not exist" when an implicit index document should be displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060394/cloudfront-s3-website-the-specified-key-does-not-exist-when-an-implicit-ind), but no luck.

Also, everything is the same when I access via Cloudfront domain `https://dq9*****u4da.cloudfront.net` or S3 bucket  domain `mys3bucket.s3-website.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com`. There is no error in my dev server btw.

Can you suggest any possible cause for this weird problem?

Thank you.

Comment: it seems working fine no 404 appeared. Share screenshot of the 404 page

Comment: @muasif80 Thanks for the comment. It seems to be a temporary bug. It's now solved and working good.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same configuration: Amazon S3 + Cloudfront React app
I think I solved it in Cloudfront

I changed the `HTTP Responde Code` from 400 to 200

[image]

Now If I go to https://example.com/signup, I dont have any 400 anymore

Comment: It worked for me now. But it is not the correct way of doing it. It is a workaround. Lambda@Edge or S3 bucket redirect might be a good solution but it didn't manage to get it working in the time being. If someone has better knowledge, please provide it. Thanks