# hosting multiple sites on S3 bucket serving index.html from directory path

Tags: amazon-s3, web-hosting, aws-cli

I'm new to using AWS S3. I want to know if it's possible to host multiple static websites in one bucket using the website route directing meta data option. I am planning to have multiple folders each with their own `index.html`, but how can I configure the bucket settings to route to each individual site when a user types the address.

For example by typing

```
http://<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/folder1
```

will take them to website 1

and

```
http://<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/folder2
```

will take them to website 2

If this is possible, is there any way to also achieve the configuration using the AWS CLI?

Comment: did you ever solve the issue? Reading the answer comments below, it sounds like it didn't work for you.  If you did find a solution, could you share it, as I'm wondering a similar question.

Comment: @fuzzi, it does not work for me as well because of CloudFront which doesn't support multiple index files, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876252/s3-multiple-index-files

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with a slight modification to the URL. You need to use the URLs as follows with the trailing slash to serve the index.html document inside folder1 and folder2.

```
http://<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/folder1/
http://<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/folder2/
```

> If you create such a folder structure in your bucket, you must have an
>   index document at each level. When a user specifies a URL that
>   resembles a folder lookup, the presence or absence of a trailing slash
>   determines the behavior of the website. For example, the following
>   URL, with a trailing slash, returns the photos/index.html index
>   document.

Reference: [Index Document Support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html)

Comment: When I use the URL with the trailing slash ,It downloads the index.html file instead of showing it !

Comment: Check the Content-Disposition header of index.html https://stackoverflow.com/q/18296875/1549165

Comment: Thanks ,that is solved.Now it fails to load sources (css,Js,..) because it looks for them at the bucket root rather than in the associated folder? it just brings up a blank page

Comment: You need to have the correct paths for css js and headers. Double check on the paths. It should work.

Comment: I use the create react app so all the configuration for the css and js are automatic

Comment: Thank you helpful for understanding a similar issue I have. When using Route53 for custom domain name the problem is still remaining. Have you seen similar behaviour ?

Comment: how do we fix deep links issue when hosting multiple websites in this manner? And deep links which are accessible from client app routing will not work anymore.